# Is there a way to search partial text in mongo database using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a node js restful api for my ecomerce store. How do i do partial text search  in my Products model using the products title eg iphone

Answer (score 0):

if your app uses one of [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#std-label-text-search-languages) languages the best way is to use text indexes in MongoDB like this :

```
db.products.createIndex( { title: "text" } )
```

and then query like this :

```
db.products.find( {$text: { $search: "iphone" } } )
```

remember you can only have one text index per collection or use compound index like this :

```
db.products.createIndex({title:"text",description:"text"})
```

for more info check [MongoDB document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-text/)

if your language not support by MongoDB you must use regex :

```
db.products.find( {title:{$regex:/iphone/}})
```

but remember it is slow

check [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for more info

Comment: ok thank you .. how about if i want to search in title and also cattegories is there a way to add options for instance seaching phone in title and categories also

    `

Comment: const searchProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const searchtext = req.body.searchtext;

    const find = Product.find({title: {$regex: searchtext , $options: "$i" }})
    .then(data => {
        res.json(data)
    })
});



the code above is wht i was now using

Comment: @CollinsJim if you want use regex it like this : find = Product.find({title: {$regex: searchtext },cattegories: {$regex:categoryText} }) but it has very bad performance just use text indexes